# Basic Roadside repairs courses

Tags: maintenance, repair, manual-transmission

I'm about to drive across Morocco over the Atlas Mountains and into the Sahara desert with a hire car ;)

Given the hire car process I have no guarantees on the make/model of the car I will get but suspect given the road conditions and distances I will be driving it is a matter of when, not if I get a brake down (I'll get road-side assistance with the hire but it could be over 24hours away).

As such I'm keen to lean how to undertake basic roadside repairs before I get into trouble.

Can anyone recommend a UK based crash course where I can learn elementary roadside repairs?

Comment: I would suggest getting a mobile device with an internet connection so you can just post the repair questions here as they come up.  But seriously, this is a good idea.  I don't know if anything exists.  Certainly a repair manual for the car and a bit-more-than-basic toolkit should also be a priority.

Comment: Are you even allowed to do that with a rental car? I'm surprised they'd allow it, never mind the insurance implications.  Have you read the fine print on the contract you're about to sign?

Comment: This almost shopping assistance or is it shopping assistance or.....hmmmm.   Beyond my pay grade.  Grey area....?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Waiting for your car repair question to be answered on Stack Exchange while being stranded in Sahara Desert? You sure that's a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this will get closed soon as 'too localised' and 'shopping'...

I don't know of any such courses, but I'd suggest getting in touch with a local community/sixth form college - find one that offers a car mechanics course/BTEC etc and talk to the teacher in charge of that course - they might be able to arrange something or put you in touch with someone.

Otherwise, talk to local car clubs or motor clubs and see if they can suggest anything. Most are populated with enthusiasts, so they may well be happy to impart some wisdom if you appear keen and genuine to them.

Take a decent basic toolkit with you, don't expect there to be anything in the car. As Zipzit says, read the hire agreement too, you don't want to get stung  for breach of contract...